# how to access custom row(s) data via Alloy?

Tags: titanium, tableview, rows, titanium-alloy

ive tried many/multiple ways to get this to work but just cant as yet, so would appreciate anyone's assistance.

i have a view as follows :

"LBProw.xml"

```
    <Alloy>
        <TableViewRow id="LBProw" >
           <ScrollableView id="sView" >
                <View id="view1"  >
                        <!-- text labels on the row -->
                        <Label id="LBPheading" >  </Label>
                        <Label id="myLabel1" >      </Label>
                        <Label id="myLabel2" >      </Label>
                </View>                     
           </ScrollableView>
        </TableViewRow>
    </Alloy>
```

- adding rows to the table is working 100% fine.

what i cant work out, is how can I loop through the previously created tableview rows, access the rows (custom) fields values, and then do something with those values. I need to access these rows (and their custom row fields values) from a different JS file.

eg. somelogic.JS <--- loop thru the table view rows, retrieve the rows custom field values and then use those values (note that $.myTable is directly accessible from this JS file)

as an example, i tried using the following but could not work out how to get the individual rows custom fields values (the label values for "LBPheading", "myLabel1", "myLabel2")

```
    // loop thru the rows    
    for (i = 0; i < $.myTable.data[0].rows.length; i++) {`
         Ti.API.info('row #' + i);
         ?? $.myTable.data[0].rows[i].????   <== how can i get the rows (custom) field values ?
    }
```

I think, it has to do with the embedded ScrollableView and View in the row ? but I cant figure out how to reference the Label(s) within that structure.

Really appreciate any assistance/advice.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you are doing it the wrong way, the UI is just for presentation and you should keep track of the model associated with each row. When the user selects a row, query the collection and retrieve the associated model... that should contain the information you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example for you to refer to. It is made in Alloy, custom rows, and dynamic updates to the tableview.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Samples-section-37535160_AlloySamples-TodoList